# For Loop to Foreach

Tags: c#, loops, for-loop, foreach

Hi there I have a `for` loop process and i want it to convert to `foreach` loop, but I cant get it working, can someone please help me?

```
int pallet = 1;
int[] res = {5,1};

foreach (int element in res)
{
  var resu = res.Length;
  if (resu < pallet)
    { }
  else { }
}

for (int i = 1; i <= res.Length; i++)
{
  if (i <= pallet)
    { }
  else { }
}
```

Comment: If the `for` loop is correct, then the `for` loop is the best way of doing this because you want the current position, which `foreach` doesn't give you. P.S. Please do not add unnecessary tags.

Comment: Two samples have different logic, in `foreach` you execute one block when array size is less than `pallet`, but in `for` loop you execute one block only when current index is less than `pallet`

Comment: _i want it to convert to foreach loop_ - why?

Comment: Doing `var resu = res.Length;` inside the `foreach` is not necessary, as the length of course does not change in each iteration.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing here really makes any sense, you are filling out an array but not using the contents. In your `for` loop you are using the index and comparing it to the pallet, not the actual array value ( `res[i-1]` ). Since you do not have any index in the `foreach` loop you have the actual element of the array being returned.  I believe that you are probably wanting something like this, but I could be wrong.

Your `for` Loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < res.Length; i++)
{
  if (res[i] <= pallet)
    { }
  else { }
}
```

Your `Foreach` Loop:

```
foreach (int element in res)
{
  if (element <= pallet)
    { }
  else { }
}
```

Comment: Of course, the `for` approach should be from zero to `< res.Length`, therefore removing the need of that `-1`.

Comment: @Andrew Your right, the array is zero based, just didn't bother to change his code other than adding comparing the array value.

Answer (score 0):

I think this may solve your problem:

```
int pallet = 1;
int[] res = { 5, 1 };

foreach (int element in res)
{
  var resu = res.Length;
  if (resu < pallet)
    { }
  else { }
}

int i = 0;
foreach (int element in res)
{
  if (i <= pallet)
    { }
  else { }
  i++;
}
```

Comment: thank you, this solve my problem thank you so much.

Comment: You could directly do `if (i++ <= pallet)` and remove the `i++` at the end.

Comment: I don't see how code for `foreach` that is identical to one in the post can "solve my problem to convert to foreach loop"... @iMemew either your problem was not related to `foreach` or … in any case please consider to edit your question to clarify what you actually having problem with.

Comment: @Alexei Pias added `int i = 0` and `i++`. I've no idea why OP wants to use a `foreach` loop for something where `for` would work better, but each to their own.

Comment: @John_ReinstateMonica Pias changed `for` part which presumably works fine... otherwise why iMemew would ask help about "*have* a for loop process and i *want it to convert* to foreach loop".

Comment: @Alexei Hmm. I thought that OP's first block was the attempt at foreach, and then the second was the working for loop. I could be completely wrong, of course. It's not 100% clear for me in the original question.

Comment: @John_ReinstateMonica That may explain the answer. I think that how I should have read this answer: "Let's ignore `foreach` code you have (also I copy-pasted it here for some reason). `for` should be translated into `foreach` with counter incremented separately as my second `foreach` shows"... (I guess I have allergy to "try this" answers :) )

Comment: @Alexei I do too (allergy), don't worry! :-)

Answer (score 0):

1. `foreach` loop: Your origin code is wrong. You can fix it to:

```
foreach (int element in res)  
{                               
  var resu = element;
  if (resu < pallet)
    { }
  else { }
}
```

2. Convert to `for` loop. I dont know why you want `i` to begin at `1`, but I do base on your origin code: To access and get value at a specific index of an array (begin at `0`), you can use `yourArray[yourIndex]`. In this, your start index of the array is `1`, you have to use `res[i-1]` instead of `res[i]`:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= res.Length; i++)
{
  if (res[i-1] <= pallet)
    { }
  else { }
}
```